# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer, supervisord

I am using gearman in production successfully in background(nohup) process.

What I want is multiple workers. For that I have used supervisor and create two processes.

After using supervisor I am getting `Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.` It is not showing any error message on supervisor process's log file.

I have stopped my backgrouond process before starting supervisor processes.

Comment: SMTP is itself not related to gearman. Do you send e-mails somewhere in your code? If yes, the error is there.

Comment: do you add the host parameter like $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; ?
and check open_ssl enabled or not.

Comment: figured out the issue with the help of SMTPDebug. i have setup environment variable for smtp host,username,password. somehow it is giving blank result for all.